# xslt: How do I wrap different tags with new tags

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm not sure this is even doable with xslt, but here goes.
I need to break the xml from articles into different parts.

I need to get all xml until the first div with class name **full-width** and wrap that in a div with class name **narrow-wrap**.
The **full-width** div needs to be wrapped with a div with class name **wide-wrap**.

Then a new div with class narrow-wrap starts and all xml until the next div with class full-width goes into that. And so on.

This is a simplified version of the xml. Tags can have nested content, as well as attributes.

```
<p>lorem</p>
<div>ipsum</div>
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>ipsum</p>
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="narrow-width">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<p>lorem</p>
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<table>ipsum</table>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>ipsum</p>        
<div class="narrow-width">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

This is how I need it to look like after transformation:

```
<div class="narrow-wrap">
    <p>lorem</p>
    <div>ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="wide-wrap">
    <div class="full-width">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="narrow-wrap">
    <p>lorem</p>
    <p>ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="wide-wrap">
    <div class="full-width">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wide-wrap">
    <div class="narrow-width">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="narrow-wrap">
    <p>lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="wide-wrap">
    <div class="full-width">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wide-wrap">
    <div class="full-width">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="narrow-wrap">
    <table>ipsum</table>
    <p>lorem</p>
    <p>ipsum</p>        
    <div class="narrow-width">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The xsl for the full-width part would be something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' full-width ')]"> 
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            wide-wrap
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The part of wrapping all the other content in blocks of divs with class narrow-wrap is beyond me though.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: 'fraid I have to downvote because this question doesn't show any research effort. What have you tried so far? How much do you know about XSLT? Is there a reason you need to use XSLT instead of other potentially more capable XML transformation methods?

Comment: @Cauterite: Downvote for lack of effort shown in the question if you must, but criticizing OP on choosing XSLT is inappropriate: (1) it's OP's call, not yours, and (2) you're wrong: there is no more capable XML transformation method.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that XSLT is necessarily a bad choice.

Comment: @Cauterite  
I am fairly new to xslt, but have some experience with easier cases. I updated my post with what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `group-adjacent` example in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples and try `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="not (@class = 'full-width')">`, then, as in the example check  the key and wrap the `current-group ()` respectively each item in the group.

Using that approach you get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="not (@class = 'full-width')">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <div class="narrow-wrap">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' full-width ')]"> 
        <div class="wide-wrap">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

online at http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxQ.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate you linking to the documentation as well as making an online example. Excellent answer.